# Wssecurity in xml desktop application

Tags: xml, vb.net, soap, ws-security, x509certificate2

I use VB.net to create soap xml file like this

> < soapEnv:Envelope >
>
> > < soapEnv:Header >
> >     < /soapEnv:Header >
> >
> > > < soapEnv:Body >
> > >
> > > < /soapEnv:Body >
> > >       < /soapEnv:Envelope>

and then i want to put a wssecurity in the header
with a signedxml in the wssecurity.

the signedxml using X509Certificate2 with signedkey public key from a .cer file

can somebody help me to implement this in VB.net Desktop Application?

Comment: This is not the way to do it. Just use "Add Service Reference". See http://johnwsaunders3.wordpress.com/2009/05/17/how-to-consume-a-web-service/

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I want to make a soap xml message into a file. i think i used to make this manually. i already download and add to reference a namespace Microsoft.Web.Service3
can i use this?

Comment: There is almost never a reason to create XML. Any design which has you creating a block of XML first is likely created by someone who is used to an environment where there are no tools - where everything has to be done by hand. You will find few examples of how to do this in VB.NET because nobody does this in VB.NET.